# Add lifecycle configuration to existing notebook in SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I started with SageMaker recently, and I'm loving it. However, I've been installing the same libraries over and over again to one of the in-built conda environments, and I want to create a life cycle configuration to do that automatically on startup. based on [the bottom of this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html):

> notebook instance lifecycle configurations are available when you create a new notebook instance.

the trouble is, I already have a notebook I've been working in for a while. Is there any way to apply a life cycle configuration on startup to an already existing notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shut the instance down, then you can edit it. Then, if you use your eyes (which I neglected to do) you can see the "Additional Configurations" section contains lifecycle configurations

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the auto-shutdown plugin available for SageMaker Studio [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-auto-shutdown-extension) and then use the `Additional Configurations` options

Answer (score 1):

I am using Sagemaker notebooks (**not** Sagemaker **Studio** Notebooks) and could not find a way to change or add a lifecycle configuration for an existing notebook. Instead I used the command line to change the lifecycle configuration of an existing notebook as:

```bash
aws sagemaker update-notebook-instance --notebook-instance-name MyNotebookName --lifecycle-config-name MyLifecycleName
```